# lxml - get attribute of child based on parent class

Tags: python, html, xpath, lxml, lxml.html

I am trying to extract hrefs from the first child of td tags with the class foo. An example DOM is:

```
<td class="foo">
   <a href="www.foobar1.com"></a>
</td>
<td class="foo">
   <a href="www.foobar2.com"></a>
</td>
```

From this I would like to get `["www.foobar1.com", "www.foobar2.com"]`

So far I have the following:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

def get_hrefs(url):
    page = requests.get(url)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
    td_elements = tree.xpath('//td[@class="foo"]')

    return [el.find("a").attrib["href"] for el in td_elements]
```

However, I feel like it would be more efficient to extend the xpath instead of doing the iteration, but not sure how to construct it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can simplify it by getting the `@href` from the `a` tag inside each `td`:

```
return tree.xpath('//td[@class="foo"]/a/@href')
```

Comment: Does this return only the first child for each td? I ask because I am getting more href's then there are td's with that class.

Comment: dom_tree.xpath('//td[@class="link"]/a[1]//@href') seems to do the trick for that case!